# Load Testing Oracle ATG ecommerce using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, atg

I have a query.
Has anyone load tested a web application written in ATG using Jmeter?

If so kindly enlighten me on how to set values for:

1. Request URL
2. Request parameters

Thanks

Comment: What is ATG? What are the specifics that you think need to be handled separately (outside normal jMeter functionality). Have you tried to save your request using jMeter proxy (or Bugzilla or BadBoy) to see what jMeter records?

Answer (score 1):

ATG is now an [Oracle Product](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/Acquisitions/atg/index.html).

As for the answer, as ATG is a very large product, some precisions should be given on which module is concerned.

I on my side have load tested with JMeter ATG ecommerce module, search engines and BCC.

It doesn't differ for what you ask from regular JMeter scripting, the best thing to do is to read [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) and once you have done this use [JMeter Proxy recording](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Regards

Philippe M.

http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com

Comment: Thanks.I too want to test ATG ecommerce.But I dont know how to specify the request URL and parameters.Does the URL change for each handle method?

Comment: I have tested a Spring mvc application using jmeter where we have a separate request URL for each action.How do we do this in ATG dynamo?